# Why does this Dict contain so many #undefs? How to ignore them?

Tags: json, undefined, julia

Using Julia, I am trying to read and interpret JSON data, but I get many `#undef`s. How to obtain an array which excludes the undefs?

```
using JSON
source = "http://api.herostats.io/heroes/1"
download(source, "1.json")
hdict  = JSON.parsefile("1.json")

#Why does hdict have so many #undefs?
hdict.vals
hdict.keys
#And how to remove them?
```

Comment: To the person who downvoted: I'd be glad to improve my question, if constructive criticism is provided. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that someone felt you could have researched this on your own fairly easily, but the appropriate thing to do would be to point you to some documentation. http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/collections/?highlight=dict#Base.Dict

Comment: `hdict.vals` and `hdict.keys` are internal data for representing the `hdict`. In order to get the keys and values, use `collect(keys(hdict))` and `collect(values(hdict))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Julia sometimes lets you do some silly things if you're not careful. In this case, you're viewing the internals of the dictionary (hash map) by accessing `hdict.keys` and `hdict.vals`, and accessing the underlying arrays that hold the items.

Try:

```
values(hdict)
keys(hdict)
```